# Which characters are allowed in a function/struct/interface name?

Tags: go

I am new to go and have started playing around with [A Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/). I noticed one peculiarity namely that I am allowed to name a function `_` but that function can not be called:

```
import "fmt"

type sel struct {
    s string
}

func _(s string) sel {
    return sel{s}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
    _("foo") // <-- does not compile
}
```

If I comment the entire `_("foo")` line then the program compiles.

My question is what characters are allowed in function names? Is it only alphanumeric characters or can I use `$` for instance?

Are the rules for naming other things e.g. structs, interfaces etc. the same as those for functions?

Comment: Interesting that although you asked about how you could name, and not why you can’t use the underscore, you accepted the answer that explained the latter, and not the one that answered the prior, your actual question. Please consider switching, or changing the question. :)

Comment: @Kissaki Good point, switched the right answere! Extra kudos to Nick though for pointing out why calling `_(s string)` didn't work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) says that func, var or const name *must* begin with (`unicode_letter` or `_`), and *can* end with any (`unicode_letter`, `unicode_digit` or `_`).

`unicode_letter` can be a Chinese, or Hebrew letter if you'd like it to.

Answer (score 10):

From the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec)

> The blank identifier, represented by the underscore character _, may
>   be used in a declaration like any other identifier but the declaration
>   does not introduce a new binding.

Which explains why the code was valid but you couldn't call the function called `_`

`_` is used in Go when you want to assign a variable but ignore it.  Calling a function _ does just the same - you defined it but the compiler will ignore it.